# Regex to split string into key/value pairs allowing for substructures

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have a string of key value pairs which I would like to split into a dictionary in Python. With the help of some other questions on here I've been able to put together some regex to achieve this at a single level:

```
(\S+?):(.+?),
```

However, a complication I have is that I would like to support sub-pairs, for example, I have this string:

```
document-name:string,document-type:string,description:string,initiative-name:string,milestone:struct<key:string,name:string>,size:int
```

This is currently being split like so:

[image: Regex101 screenshot]

So as you can see it is currently treating the comma in the middle of what is the value of the "milestone" pair as the start of a new pair.

I am planning on using recursion at the code level to deal with this one the splitting has been accomplished successfully, as there is potentially infinite depth. But is there a way I can have it ignore the commas when they are wrapped by brackets, or something similar?

Comment: "*when they are wrapped by brackets*" - can you share an example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant angle brackets as per the example in the question, but to be extra clear I would like `milestone:struct<key:string,name:string>` to be treated as a single key/value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `re` library does not support recursion in regular expressions, so either you'd have to import an alternative regular expression library, or you could write a parser that makes the nested dictionary at the same time. This parser would still use a regular expression, but just to tokenise the input. The parser can then use its own stack to apply and verify the nesting.

This solution takes that route:

```
import re

def parse(s):
    regex = r"([^:<>,]+):(?:(struct)<|([^:<>,]*)(>*),?)|(\w+|.)"
    stack = []
    d = {}
    for match in re.finditer(regex, s):
        key, opening, value, closing, invalid = match.group(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        if opening:
            d[key] = {}
            stack.append(d)
            d = d[key]
        elif invalid:
            raise ValueError(f"expected key:value, but found '{invalid}'")
        elif not value:
            raise ValueError(f"missing value after colon")
        else:
            d[key] = value
            if closing:
                if len(closing) > len(stack):
                    raise ValueError(f"too many '{closing}'")
                d = stack[-len(closing)]
                del stack[-len(closing):]
    if stack:
        raise ValueError("missing '>'")
    return d
```

Example call:

```
s = "document-name:string,document-type:string,description:string,initiative-name:string,milestone:struct<key:string,name:struct<s:string>>,size:int"
d = parse(s)
```

`d` will be:

```
{
  'document-name': 'string',
  'document-type': 'string',
  'description': 'string',
  'initiative-name': 'string',
  'milestone': {
    'key': 'string',
    'name': {
      's': 'string'
    }
  },
  'size': 'int'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the regex should match `milestone` as a key and `struct<key:string,name:string>` as a value. If so then you can use

```
(\S+?):([^:]*?<.*>|.+?)(?:,|$)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LtODhE/1)

As the regex above is not the best solution for your problem I decided to provide a Python function to convert such strings to a Python `dict`.

```py
import re
import json


def convert(string):
    string = re.sub(r">", "}", string)
    string = re.sub(r"(?<=:)(struct<)", "{", string)

    string = re.sub(r"(^|,|{)(.*?)(?=:)", "\\1\"\\2\"", string)
    string = re.sub(r"(:)([^{}]*?)(?=$|,|})", "\\1\"\\2\"", string)

    return json.loads("{%s}" % string)
```

**NOTE:** This works without recursion but works properly

```py
struct = "document-name:string,document-type:string,description:string,initiative-name:string,milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>,milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>,size:int"

print(convert(struct))  # {'document-name': 'string', 'document-type': 'string', 'description': 'string', 'initiative-name': 'string', 'milestone': {'foo': {'a': 'bar', 'b': 'baz'}, 'name': 'string'}, 'size': 'int'}
```

Comment: You fixed that problem, but unfortunately created another. Try input `milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>,milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a capture a single key-value pair with a single regular expression, then you cannot use standard regular expressions, since regular expression do not support recursive structures. You can, however use the [regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), which has added support for recursion.

Your expression could be something like: `([^:<>,]+):(struct\<(?R)+\>|[^:<>+]+)(,|$|(?=>))`.
Breakdown:

1. `([^:<>,]+):` - the key and colon
2. `(struct\<(?R)+\>|[^:<>+]+)` - the value, either:

   1. `struct\<(?R)+\>` - a struct value (`(?R)` means "recurse" in the `regex` library)
   2. or a value, e.g. `"string"`
3. `(,|$|(?=>))` - the ending: must be either a comma, end of input or forward lookahead to a `>` character.

Here is a more complete parser (pretty much the same regular expression, but using named groups):

```
import regex

pattern = regex.compile(
    r"([^:<>,]+):(struct\<(?P<rec_value>(?R)+)\>|(?P<value>[^:<>+]+))(,|$|(?=>))"
)


def parse(s):
    return {
        match[1]: parse(match["rec_value"]) if match["rec_value"] else match["value"]
        for match in pattern.finditer(s)
    }


print(
    parse(
        "document-name:string,document-type:string,description:string,initiative-name:string,milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>,milestone:struct<foo:struct<a:bar,b:baz>,name:string>,size:int"
    )
)
```

Output:

```
{
    "document-name": "string",
    "document-type": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "initiative-name": "string",
    "milestone": {"foo": {"a": "bar", "b": "baz"}, "name": "string"},
    "size": "int"
}
```

Note that this will not error on malformed input, e.g. `a:A,b::B,c:C`, will just silently ignore the `b::B` error. A little more work would be needed to catch errors like this.